# Time Synchronization Between Two Computers using the DOS prompt

Tags: timestamp

I have a problem that I am stumped on. I need to sync the clocks between two computers without using NTP (that was my first solution but my boss said they may not be hooked up to the network 100% of the time). t doesn't have to be the correct time so to speak, as long as the time is the same for both computers. I would prefer to do this in the DOS prompt as I am not sure what OS the other computer might be running. I was told the utility **w32m** may provide the synchronization required but have not found much information on that utility. Any help would be appreciated. This is my first question on here but I have used your answers a lot in the past.

Comment: off topic (not a programming question). May I suggest superuser next time?

Comment: Sorry, like I said first time asking a question. What is Superuser? I can definitely see myself using this site more often though :-) Just have to make sure I get my questions in the right topics.

Comment: Superuser is http://superuser.com/ , part of the same Stackexchange network of Q&A sites as Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not sure what OS the other is running then you should definitely use NTP! It's really the only cross-platform time synchronization protocol, and besides, it's the best one.

NTP will handle the situation where the computers are not communicating with each other 100% of the time just fine. I assume that Internet access may be even more unreliable, but that's OK since one of the computers could be configured as a stratum 1 source if necessary (or connected to a stratum 1 source such as a GPS).